# How can i encrypt an email id and it decrypt it back but has string length should be 30-40 .?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

i want to **encrypt a email id** which **encrypted string length** should be **30-40**

```
email@gmail.com // should be 20-40 encrypted sting
```

*and want to decrypt that sting backto email id*

thanks in advance

Comment: Encryption and Hashing are not the same thing. The latter isn't reversable. The Node Crypto docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher) have a good example of a basic string encryption and decription but the length of your encrypted string will depend on the method you use.

Comment: `which encrypted string length should be 30-40` Why? Why is it important to you to possibly inflate the result?

Comment: Thanks @gavin , i have already tried  with Crypto ,can you suggest  me method for smaller string in **Crypto**,

Comment: @Thomas i am making url endpoint with string ,and url got bigger due to string

Comment: I find this question hard to understand because the author obviously did not make an attempt towards legibility or even punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you need such a tight length in the url? The Node Crypto example  will work as so:

**Note that using 'ctr' and especially no salt & IV has potential security problems, but will get you a pretty small string**

passing in:

```js
let password = 'mypass';
let plain = 'email@domain.com';

enc(plain, password).then((encrypted)=>{
    console.log('enc resolved with:', encrypted); // enc resolved with: 179075be892ef35bc519f47a23695644
    dec(encrypted, password).then((decrypted)=>{
        console.log('dec resolved with:', decrypted); // dec resolved with: email@domain.com
    })
})
```

with functions from example:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

let enc = (plaintext, pass)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const algorithm = 'aes-192-ctr';
        // Key length is dependent on the algorithm. In this case for aes192, it is
        // 24 bytes (192 bits).
        // Use async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
        const key = crypto.scryptSync(pass, '', 24);
        // Use `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
        // shown here.
        const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

        let encrypted = '';
        cipher.on('readable', () => {
          let chunk;
          while (null !== (chunk = cipher.read())) {
            encrypted += chunk.toString('hex');
          }
        });
        cipher.on('end', () => {
            return resolve(encrypted)
        });
        cipher.write( plaintext );
        cipher.end();
    })
}

let dec = (enctext, pass)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const algorithm = 'aes-192-ctr';
        // Key length is dependent on the algorithm. In this case for aes192, it is
        // 24 bytes (192 bits).
        // Use async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
        const key = crypto.scryptSync(pass, '', 24);
        // Use `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
        // shown here.
        const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

        let decrypted = '';
        decipher.on('readable', () => {
        while (null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
            decrypted += chunk.toString('utf8');
        }
        });
        decipher.on('end', () => {
            return resolve(decrypted);
        });
        decipher.write(enctext, 'hex');
        decipher.end();

    })
}
```